# Why does Styles.Render not work inside curly braces?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to structure some of my template files a little better and I decided to use the ViewBag to store the actuel CSS theme I need for the page. On the page itself I have code that reads:

```
ViewBag.Theme = "~/Content/MyTheme";
```

In my template I have the following code, which does not render anything:

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.Theme!= null)
    {
        Styles.Render(ViewBag.Theme);            
    }
}
```

The following does work:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/MyTheme");
```

But this won't:

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.Theme!= null)
    {
        Styles.Render("~/Content/MyTheme");            
    }
}
```

Or this

```
@{          
    Styles.Render("~/Content/MyTheme");
}
```

I did add the correct line to my BundleConfig.cs file. Because otherwise it would never work. At this point I am really confused. Did I hit a bug or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.Theme!= null)
    {
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/MyTheme");            
    }
}
```

It returns a string, that the `@` should handle.